# How to save default JavaScript datetime object in django

Tags: javascript, django, format

I want to save default JavaScript datetime format in django database. How can I change the datetime field format in django default to JavaScript format? For example: This JavaScript format: `Mon Feb 06 2017 11:39:05 GMT+0000 (GMT)` while django's models.DateTimeField expects: `2017-02-06 11:39` ?

Comment: You can play around with the `DATETIME_FORMAT` setting and `USE_L10N=False`

Comment: Not sure about default but you can change new instance of date somewhat like this for display in templates
`
var dateOptions = {option: 'value'};
var datetime = new Date(data['datetime']).toLocaleString('en', dateOptions);
`